# How to instruct pandas to return 0 if it is trying to divide 0 by 0?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df

When I execute the following line:

```
df['var3'] = df['var1']/df['var2']
```

I get:

```
ID  date  var1   var2   var3
A   2019Q3  1      2     0.5
A   2019Q4  1      1      1
B   2019Q3  0     NaN    NaN
B   2019Q4  0      0     NaN
...
```

Is there a way to tell python to return 0 if it is trying to divide 0 by 0?
so,

```
ID  date  var1   var2   var3
A   2019Q3  1      2     0.5
A   2019Q4  1      1      1
B   2019Q3  0     NaN    NaN
B   2019Q4  0      0     *0*
...
```

Comment: Only for 0/0? Or any number/0 as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fast solution would be adding this line after the division:

```
df.loc[(df['var1'] == 0) & (df['var2']== 0), 'var3'] = df[(df['var1'] == 0) & (df['var2']== 0)].fillna(0)
```

In this way you are selecting rows in which var1 and var2 are equal to 0 and filling the nan with 0.